# Is there a limit of 5 iterations in a looping workflow? Is it documented somewhere?

Tags: list, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a "looping" set of workflows, something like this:

User creates item in List1, triggering a.  The group of workflows then create a number of duplicates of the item in list1 (number of dupes desired is a column in List1):

```
 a. List1 Workflow (on new item creation): create item in List2
 b. List2 Workflow (on new item creation): decrement a counter column in List2, call update on this item.
 c. List2 Workflow (on item edited): if counter > 0, then:
    c1. create item in List1 (this does NOT trigger a.)
    c2. create item in List2 (this DOES trigger b. )
```

For counters of <=5 this works perfectly.  However, any number greater than five, the process just quits after the 5th iteration (whether I enter 6 or 8 or 13 etc).

I guess this may be desired to prevent runaway/infinite loops, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Is there a limit of 5 iterations within a workflow like the one described? If so where is it documented?